# Doctrine2: Should parent classes in single table inheritance be abstract?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm writing constructors for my classes in a Doctrine2 application, let's say Fruits, Apple, Bananas.

`Fruits` is the parent class, where `Apples` and `Bananas` inherit from `Fruits` using single table inheritance on field `type`.

On the Doctrine2 documentation page, there is an example provided for single table inheritance. If we are always discriminating using Single Table Inheritance, should the base class `Fruits` be abstract because the discriminator field must always be set? If so, should the constructor for `Fruits` also be protected to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are no methods in your parent class "Fruits" that you need to redeclare I don't think there is an explicit need for it to be declared as abstract.

Also you may find a use case where you may want an instance of "Fruit" to be persisted (undetermined as to what type of fruit it is). Marking the parent as abstract will prevent you from being able to do this.

Maybe fruit is a bad example. But the Person example they have in the documentation is better. Employees will inherit Person definitions. But I may also want to persist just an instance of Person, undetermined of type. Hence the "person" = "Person" in the @DiscriminatorMap.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks! I realized I didn't catch the subtlety of discriminating the parent object in the documentation. For my application, I do not want a superclass type, I want it to be one of the children, so perhaps in that case it is alright?

Comment: If you feel the parent should never be instantiated, personally, I'd go with making the constructor private. But yes, mould your Entities to your application requirements, that's what they're there for. Also, the discriminator field is used internally by doctrine. There should never be a need to set / fetch on this.